# Advice about microsd current consumption

Tags: power, circuit-design, current-limiting, sd

I'm designing circuit with STM32L0 MCU that storage some data in microSD via SPI interface.

I have power budget of 5V @ 500mA via VBUS so, I would like to estimate microsd's current consumption.

I have seen two posts([1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33472/how-much-current-does-a-microsd-card-use), [2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/247734/what-determines-the-actual-power-consumption-of-writing-to-a-microsd-card)) about microSD current consumption.
to sum it up, the answers in both posts says that current consumption is variant and vendor specific. it differents from microsd to another.

could you please suggest me what to do about it?
How should I design the circuit with a variant gap of current consumption?

For example, limit the microsd's current consumption to 150mA and put current limiting IC at microsd's VDD pin?

*EDIT: 
my circuit also contains 8ohm 0.2W speaker that power from 3.3V power rail. speaker's current consumption is about 160mA. only the speaker and the microSD alone current consumption is about ~300mA.
the application should record data on demand from UART and write it to micro sd card in real-time. every 2sec the system should write data, 16Kbytes, to micro sd card. meanwhile, the application should play a couple of sounds in different frequencies. my concern is to exceed VBUS current consumption (500mA) while the speaker and the microSD are on*

Comment: You really don't want to do that. If you put a current limiter and the SD card tries to exceed that, the voltage will droop and the card will likely malfunction. You probably want to be trying to limit the CPU consumption while the SD card is running.

Comment: I'm no expert on these devices, but I believe there are "lower power" modes for operation. In addition, you may be able to slowly "pump up" enough energy onto a capacitor, sufficient to operate the microSD for some (set of) small operation(s); then re-pump it, and continue. Slower. But it means you could stay under some limitation that way. (I'm assuming here that changing the MCU itself isn't warranted because (a) too late, too hard; and, (b) it's not the real problem in any regard. [Otherwise, you might also consider other MCUs with much lower power, as part of your overall considerations.])

Comment: @jonk could you please to go into details with your idea about "pump up" enough energy onto a cap? it sounds interesting.

Comment: Playing games with the card's power is a bad idea.  Pragmatically speaking, cards are operated in USB-spec readers all the time, so unless the rest of your circuit is very hungry in ways you have not stated, you are probably ok.  How much storage do you actually need?  The situation with a well chosen, soldered-in SPI flash is likely to be more deterministic (since it's a single non-user-substitutable part with an actual data sheet), and you can get up to 32 megabytes in that format fairly easily.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I need a couple of KBs but I don't want to be size dependent. also, it can't be soldered-in flash. my circuit also contains 8ohm 0.2W speaker that power from 3.3V power rail. speaker's current consumption is about 160mA. only the speaker and the microSD alone current consumption is about ~300mA

Comment: @MercuryAvangburg You should memorialize what you just wrote in your question. You've provided important information in a comment that should be in the question. And now I'm wondering if you are reading from the microSD in order to drive the speaker in "real-time." Is that the case?

Comment: For kilobytes, I have to say a card sounds like a bad idea.  Just the socket for it would cost as much as a healthily oversized flash.  For that matter, have you ruled out the using the *internal* flash or EEprom the STM32L0 ?

Comment: @jonk I have been added the information to my question. thank you! the microsd is to write software's log.

Comment: @MercuryAvangburg So you are operating the speaker and periodically updating the flash, from time to time? How often? How much must be written each time? How much internal RAM do you have for buffering the data? Can't you write more?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I need to be able to store the data and manipulate it later. the usage of microSD is mandatory for my soultion

Comment: @jonk the writes to the microSD should be continuous. I need to be able to make a sound while I write data to the microSD. each time I make a 'microsd write' I should 'play' sound from RAM.

Comment: If you're insistent on using a consumer micro SD card rather than an engineering component with data available, you have an off topic question about the usage of consumer electronics.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't understand your comment. my application required a portable storage media. as part of my application design, I make 'power budget' diagram. because of that, I need to know micro sd's power consumption. why my question is off topic?

Comment: @MercuryAvangburg Your answer (continuous writes) makes no sense to me. There is never a requirement for "continuous writes" unless your data rate can only barely be sustained by the device (fast, lots of data) and you have no buffering ram, either. Talk a LOT MORE about what you need to achieve. Don't state conclusions (like "continuous") but instead state goals and provide your logic and reasoning *why* you conclude certain things. It's okay to have a conclusion, but we need to understand your axioms and sound reasoning from them in order to agree or disagree. Expose your thinking.

Comment: @jonk my application should record data on demand from UART and write it to micro sd card in real-time. every 2sec the system should write data, 16Kbytes, to micro sd card. meanwhile, the application should play a couple of sounds in different frequencies.

my concern is to exceed VBUS current consumption (500mA) while the speaker and the microSD are on. as I said both of them are sink ~300mA and I don't want to be close to this constraint

Comment: @MercuryAvangburg Your speaker is a given, of course. It's a continuous draw. Can't argue there. Your 8kb/s data rate is vital. Do you know how long it takes (worst case) to write 16kb to the microSD? (You should just burst that once every 2 seconds, but I'm pretty sure the write doesn't take 2 seconds to complete.)

Comment: "every 2sec the system should write data, 16Kbytes, to micro sd card. meanwhile, the application should play a couple of sounds in different frequencies... each time I make a 'microsd write' **I should 'play' sound** from RAM" - Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my experience, typical SD card current consumption is ~30mA in SPI mode and ~100mA in 4-bit SD mode. My advice would be to include the first figure with a 2x or 3x safety margin (that is, 60 or 90 mA) in your device power budget, and make sure that the rest of your circuit never consumes more than 500-60 = 440mA or 500-90 = 410mA respectively.

Actively limiting the current consumed by the SD card makes little sense, considering it consumes less that 10% of the overall power. Disabling the speaker when VBUS drops below 4.75V would make more sense. If you absolutely want to control SD card power consumption, send the IDLE command instead of cutting the power.

Answer (score 3):

The SD specification does have power limits. With UHS, there are even programmable current limits. Which will probably reduce the card performance.

It would be wise to consult [the standard](https://www.sdcard.org) in this case, to see which classes of cards you're looking to support.

If the design and budget constraints allow it, I would place a high side switch with current limit.
This way you can control the power to the card. This has advantages, it allows you to reboot the card, and prevent a full short on a faulty card.
You can also behave like a nice USB device not drawing too much current when not allowed.

Comment: *I would place a high side switch with current limit* -- or a [PTC polyfuse, e.g. this one that trips at 150mA](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Littelfuse/1210L005WR?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsxR%252bBXi4wRUOzbUMDaaSJ5rOTIqgi3YbA%3d).